# importError: No module named 'django.db.backends.util'

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I am using MySql db.i made following changes but now i am getting following error

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'test',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'USER': 'mssql',
        'PASSWORD': 'mssql',
        'PORT': '1434'
    }
}
```

> "ImportError: No module named 'django.db.backends.util' "

Comment: how to connect mssql db from django.as django does not provide default engine for mssql.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably installed `django-mssql` version 1.7 which supports <= Django 1.8.

You can try `django-mssql-1.8b2`:

```
pip install django-mssql==1.8b2
```

Beware that this is probably a beta version, so it might not be suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you don't have suitable db backends for `mssql`. You can install https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc as db backend.